# Send command line from an exe to another exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line, communication

I have two c++ programs ,lets say prog1 and prog2. I need to start prog2 and send data to it, from prog1 by command line.
I would like to know where I can find some documentation or tutorials on this matter ? I searched the internet but could not find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Googling tips: on Windows, `CreateProcess`. On POSIX, `exec`-family of functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use CreateProcess function.
Something like this:
    LPTSTR arguments = "/s /f d:\test";
    CreateProcess("C:\win\calc.exe", cmdArgs, NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,null,null);